# How do I set the value of a specific cell using xlsx (R package)?

Tags: r, package, xlsx

I'm trying to set the value of a specific cell in xlsx. I'm doing this to add a title for the data frame that I added in Excel, but I can't figure it out. I tried `createCells`, `createRows`, `getCells` and `getRows`, but I can't seem to get any of them to work despite reading the documentation.

Comment: Could you post the code you have created to get to the point where you want to add a title?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without benefit of seeing your code and knowing exactly what you are trying to do, I suggest trying

```
setCellValue(cell, value)
```

For example, starting from scratch and creating a new excel file:

```
wb    <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")           # create an empty workbook
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="Sheet1")   # create an empty sheet 
rows  <- createRow(sheet, rowIndex=1:10)       # 10 rows
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:6)        # 6 columns in each row
setCellValue(cells[[1,2]], "Data Frame Title Goes Here")   # put in Row 1, Column 2
```